# In numpy, how can I randomly choose a number from a range that excludes a random number that was previously chosen?

Tags: python, numpy, random

For example:

```
open_door = np.random.randint(1,4)
prize_behind_door = np.random.randint(1,4)
change_door = np.random.randint(1,4)
```

But I don't want change_door to have a value that is the same as open_door, while it is still random (so it can be equal to prize_behind_door), what commands should I use?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`np.setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) to set a range that excludes `open_door` and then use [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) to choose one random element off it -

```
np.random.choice(np.setdiff1d(range(1,4), open_door))
```

Sample runs -

```
In [329]: open_door = np.random.randint(1,4)
     ...: prize_behind_door = np.random.randint(1,4)
     ...: 

In [330]: open_door
Out[330]: 2

In [331]: prize_behind_door
Out[331]: 1

In [349]: np.setdiff1d(range(1,4), open_door) # array that excludes open_door
Out[349]: array([1, 3])

In [332]: np.random.choice(np.setdiff1d(range(1,4), open_door))
Out[332]: 1

In [333]: np.random.choice(np.setdiff1d(range(1,4), open_door))
Out[333]: 3

In [334]: np.random.choice(np.setdiff1d(range(1,4), open_door))
Out[334]: 3

In [335]: np.random.choice(np.setdiff1d(range(1,4), open_door))
Out[335]: 3

In [336]: np.random.choice(np.setdiff1d(range(1,4), open_door))
Out[336]: 1
```

Comment: Thank you this is a very concise answer. What if I want to exclude two numbers randomly selected previously? For example, now the range is (1,8), and I randomly choose two numbers. And then I choose the third number, which should be randomly chosen and excluding the previous two.

Comment: @hephaes Use `np.setdiff1d(range(1,8), open_door)`, where `open_door` has those two previous choosen values as a list or array containing those two elements and as again use `np.random.choice` on it : `np.random.choice(np.setdiff1d(range(1,8), open_door))`. So, nothing changes really.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a while loop

```
open_door = np.random.randint(1,4)
prize_behind_door = np.random.randint(1,4)
while True:
  x = np.random.randint(1,4)
  if x != open_door:
    change_door = x 
    break
```

If you want to disclude multiple values you could just add to the if statement

```
if x != value_1 and x != value_2:
  value_3 = x
  break
```

Another way to do it is by creating a bool array that's the same length as the range of random numbers.

If the value of the bool array with the index of the chosen number is False it means that value hasn't been selected already, if it's true it means it has.

Inside a while loop check if the value has been chosen by getting the result of bool_array[chosen_number]. If it has been ignore and chose a new number, otherwise append that value to an array that you're using to represent your values and set the value of the bool array with the index of that number to True to represent that it's been chosen now.

I'll do this inside of a function to keep things organized

```
from random import randint    

def select_random_numbers(rand_range, values):

  temp_list = []
  isPicked = [False for _ in range(rand_range)]

  for i in range(values):
    while True:
      x = randint(0, rand_range - 1)
      if isPicked[x] == False:
        temp_list.append(x)
        isPicked[x] = True
        break
  return(temp_list)


print(select_random_numbers(10, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `choice` without `replace`?

```
In [230]: np.random.choice(range(1,4),2, replace=False)
Out[230]: array([2, 3])
In [231]: np.random.choice(range(1,4),2, replace=False)
Out[231]: array([2, 3])
In [232]: np.random.choice(range(1,4),2, replace=False)
Out[232]: array([1, 3])
In [233]: np.random.choice(range(1,4),2, replace=False)
Out[233]: array([1, 2])
In [234]: np.random.choice(range(1,4),2, replace=False)
Out[234]: array([3, 2])
In [235]: np.random.choice(range(1,4),2, replace=False)
Out[235]: array([3, 2])
In [236]: open_door, change_door = np.random.choice(range(1,4),2, replace=False)
     ...: 
In [237]: open_door
Out[237]: 3
In [238]: change_door
Out[238]: 1
```

The 2 values will be random, but always different.  And this selection will be independent of the one for `prize_behind_door`.

For 2 values from a small range like this, the Python `random` module will be as good, if not better (quick time tests show it's faster):

```
random.sample(range(1,4),2)
```

Comment: `replace=False` has a [truly awful implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/34075a54e7aa10e80d41ef33ec7102292ecff0d5/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L1185) that I think they're stuck with for backward compatibility reasons. It's fine for choosing from `range(1, 4)`, but it can be a serious performance killer for small samples from large arrays.

Comment: Do you like `random.sample` any better?

Comment: `random.sample` is smarter about how it generates the sample. Which one performs better depends on the particular parameters; I'd probably prefer it for this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a list of random numbers such as those numbers are diffrent than the already choosed ones.

```
i=np.random.randint(1,4)
elements=np.array([k for k in range(1,4) if k!=i])
j=elements[np.random.randint(0,len(elements)-1)]
```